# Get selected cell in RadGridView Telerik

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, radgridview

Need to get the cell edited with the button click where the button is bound to the cell. I'm trying to get, but still its returning first row.

**XAML:**

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="ABC"   DataMemberBinding="{Binding ABC, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ABC}">                                             
              <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding ABC}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
              <TextBlock Text="Link" />                                                                 
              </Hyperlink>                                                                   
             <telerik:RadRibbonButton Content="Edit" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Size="Small" Width="25" 
SmallImage="..\Images\Edit_16.png" LargeImage="..\Images\Edit_32.png"  Click="RadButtons_Click"></telerik:RadRibbonButton>
              </TextBlock>                                                          
         </DataTemplate>                                                    
         </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

**XAML.cs**:

```
private void RadButtons_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
            this.grdgetval.CurrentCellInfo // This always returns the first row
            this.grdgetval.BeginEdit();        
    }
```

Where i'm wrong? and what needs to be added?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what you want but you could try one of the following:

```
this.radGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnInfo.Name
this.radGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Picture Name"].Value
this.radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value
```

I hope this is of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the current cell in **Edit Mode** programmatically, you have to use following code -

```
this.grdgetval.CurrentCell.BeginEdit()
```

If you want to edit a cell on a button click (I assume that is your case), you have to set the desired cell as **CurrentCell** first, as shown below -

```
this.grdgetval.CurrentCellInfo = cellToEdit; // cellToEdit-the cell to be edited    
this.grdgetval.BeginEdit();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The CurrentCell always returns me the first row.